# Require another click for mouseover function

Tags: jquery, click, mouseover

I'm trying to make a bar on the top of a page that once clicked, allows the user to change the background color of the page by mousing over a div. The problem is, this bar stays active indefinitely, so that if the user unintentionally mouses over the bar again, the color will change.

I'd like the user to have to click again to reactivate the mouseover functions.

I have a simplified version of what I'm using on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FfpEF/).

Here is the script:

```
 $(function () {
    config = {
        sensitivity: 3,
        interval: 200,
        timeout: 500,
        over: function () {
            $('#colorBar').animate({
                "height": "50px"
            }, 500);
        },
        out: function () {
            $('#colorBar').animate({
                "height": "20px"
            }, 200);
        }
    }
    $('#colorBar').hoverIntent(config)
});

$("#colorBar").click(

function () {
    $("#red").mouseover(

    function () {
        $("body").css("background-color", "red");
    });
    $("#green").mouseover(

    function () {
        $("body").css("background-color", "green");
    });
    $("#blue").mouseover(

    function () {
        $("body").css("background-color", "blue");
    });
    $("#yellow").mouseover(

    function () {
        $("body").css("background-color", "yellow");
    });
});
```

Comment: How do you know when a user has firmly selected a color and isn't just flicking through them? You could try debouncing the same function in each mouseover that calls `$.unbind('mouseover')`

Comment: You can simplify your `click` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/FfpEF/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unbind your mouseover event somehow. One way to do it:

change your config to this:

```
config = {
    sensitivity: 3, // number = sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)
    interval: 200, // number = milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval
    timeout: 500, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut
    over: function() { $('#colorBar').animate({"height": "50px"}, 500); }, // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)
    out: function() { $('#colorBar').animate({"height": "20px"}, 200); $('.color').unbind("mouseover"); } // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the simple answer. I had tried .unbind and a dozen other things, but I was mistakenly applying it on the parent element.